# Read all system log android

Tags: android, logging, output

When I have my phone connected to Eclipse I can read all the log messages from the logcat without any filter. I'm trying to read all these logs on my app programmatically. I'm trying this code:

```
private String getLogOutput(){
    StringBuilder log = new StringBuilder();
    try {
          Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d");
          BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
          new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));         
          String line;
          while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
              log.append(line);
          }
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    return log.toString();
}
```

but it only return the logs of my app (not all the messages shown on the logcat.

Anyone know how to get it?

Thanks!!

Comment: http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/07/12/read-logs-regression.html

Comment: I supposed there are security limitations and I believed I couldn't get it without root. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant read all the logs.

read [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_LOGS)

> public static final String READ_LOGS
>
> Added in API level 1 Allows an application to read the low-level
>   system log files.
>
> Not for use by third-party applications, because Log entries can
>   contain the user's private information.
>
> Constant Value: "android.permission.READ_LOGS"

Answer (score 1):

you can't read the logs of other apps unless on a rooted device.

Comment: I am using `logcat -d` command in my rooted device application its returning only current app logs not all system logs will you please help?